# Single hive query to remove certain text in data

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a column data like this in 2 formats

**1)`"/abc/testapp/v1?FirstName=username&Lastname=test123"`**

**2)`"/abc/testapp/v1?FirstName=username"`**

I want to retrieve the output as **`"/abc/testapp/v1?FirstName=username"`** and strip out the data starting with "&Lastname" and ending with "".The idea is to remove the Lastname with its value.
But if the data doesn't contain "&Lastname" then it should also work fine as per the second scenario
The value for Lastname shown in the example is "test123" but in general this will be dynamic

I have started with regexp_replace but i am able to replace "&Lastname" but not its value.
`select regexp_replace("/abc/testapp/v1?FirstName=username&Lastname=test123&type=en_US","&Lastname","");`
Can someone please help here how i can achieve both these with a single hive query?

Comment: is this the output you wanted ?

Comment: we cannot hardcode the value of LastName as "&Lastname=test123" ...In the example I have given "test123" as value but in general it can be anything .Edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use split function:

```
with your_data as (--Use your table instead of this example
select stack (2,
              "/abc/testapp/v1?FirstName=username&Lastname=test123",
              "/abc/testapp/v1?FirstName=username"
             ) as str
)

select split(str,'&')[0] from your_data;
```

Result:

```
_c0
/abc/testapp/v1?FirstName=username
/abc/testapp/v1?FirstName=username
```

Or use '&Lastname' pattern for split:

```
select split(str,'&Lastname')[0] from your_data;
```

It will allow something else with & except starting with &Lastname

Answer (score 0):

for both queries with or without last name its working in this way using `split` for hive no need for any table to select you can directly execute the function like `select functionname`

```
select    
split("/abc/testapp/v1FirstName=username&Lastname=test123",'&')[0]
```

```
select    
split("/abc/testapp/v1FirstName=username",'&')[0]
```

Result :

```
 _c0
    /abc/testapp/v1FirstName=username
```

you can make a single query :

```
select    
split("/abc/testapp/v1FirstName=username&Lastname=test123",'&')[0],
split("/abc/testapp/v1FirstName=username",'&')[0]
```

```
 _c0                                        _c1
    /abc/testapp/v1FirstName=username    /abc/testapp/v1FirstName=username
```

Comment: Hello @Ram we cannot hardcode the value of LastName as "&Lastname=test123" ...In the example I have given "test123" as value but in general it can be anything